# Convert database result table to a meaningful output aggregating similar values

Tags: php

I get a result table from database like following.

```
+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+--------------+
| subject     | payment    | amount | student_count | total_amount |
+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+--------------+
| Mathematics | 2018 May   |    500 |             9 |         4500 |
| Mathematics | 2018 May   |    250 |             1 |          250 |
| Mathematics | 2018 April |    500 |            13 |         6500 |
+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+--------------+
```

I want to generate a summary from this as following to send an SMS summary.

```
Mathematics
-
2018 May
500*9=4500
250*1=250
Total=4750
-
2018 April
500*13=6500
Total=6500
-
Net Total=11250
```

I could get the details through following PHP code without **Total** and **Net Total**. In my code summing up caused a problem as the last row of a table could not be identified in `foreach`.

```
$subject = '';
$payment = '';
$amount = '';

foreach($result as $row){
  if($subject != $row['subject']){
    $subject = $row['subject'];
    echo "\n-\n".$subject;
    $payment = '';
  }
  if($payment != $row['payment']){
    $payment = $row['payment'];
    echo "\n-\n".$payment;
    $amount = '';
  }
  if($amount != $row['amount']){
    $amount = $row['amount'];
    echo "\n".intval($amount)."*".$row['student_count']."=".intval($row['total_amount']);
  }
}
```

It's highly appreciated if somebody could help out to get the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these scenarios when you are tallying something and outputting in a loop after summing data from  *previous rows*, you always have to do a final output for the last row.  You just need some extra outputs after the loop:

```
$total=0;
$grandtotal=0;
foreach($result as $row){
   if($subject != $row['subject']){
     echo 'Net total= '.$grandtotal;
     $grandtotal=0;
     $subject = $row['subject'];
     echo "\n-\n".$subject;
     $payment = '';
   }
   if($payment != $row['payment']){
     echo 'Total= '.$total;
     $total=0;
     $payment = $row['payment'];
     echo "\n-\n".$payment;
     $amount = '';
   }
   if($amount != $row['amount']){
      $amount = $row['amount'];
      echo "\n".intval($amount)."*".$row['student_count']."=".intval($row['total_amount']);
      $grandtotal+=$row['total_amount'];
      $total+=$row['total_amount'];
   }
}
//Flush final data 
echo 'Total= '.$total;
echo 'Net Total= '.$grandtotal
```

It seems in-elegant, but I've never found a way around this.
Also, do you really want the `if($amount != $row['amount'])` would this not skip a row where the amounts happen to match?

Comment: I adjusted the answer a little to properly output content. Thanks for the answer. That was helpful.